# Brownian Motion hitting time is finite yet has infinite expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I've read that a hitting time of a Brownian motion (defined as $T_a = \inf\{t\ge0:W_t=a\}$ where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian Motion, i.e. a Wiener process), has the following two properties, which I am trying to understand:

$$ \mathbb{P}(T_a \lt \infty ) = 1 $$

$$ \mathbb{E}[T_a]=\infty $$

These are from pg 6 of http://www.pstat.ucsb.edu/faculty/ludkovski/bmNotes.pdf, for example.

My question is what these mean and how they are not in conflict.  I interpret the first one to say that with probability one the hitting time for any $a$ is finite.  I interpret the second one to say that the expectation of the stopping time for any $a$ is infinite.  This seems in conflict to me (i.e. saying that something is finite with probability one yet has infinite expectation?).  Please help me gain some intuition here, and correct me if I am misunderstanding one or both of these properties.

Comment: Similar situation, maybe simpler: assume $N$ is discrete, with positive integer values and such that $$P(N=n)=\frac1{n(n+1)}$$ for every $n\geqslant1$, then $N$ is almost surely finite because $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(N=n)=1$$ and its expectation is infinite because $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\,P(N=n)=+\infty.$$

Comment: The [St. Petersburg lottery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox) is another example of something which is almost surely finite but has infinite expectation.  Another (more closely related to Brownian motion) is the expected first return time of a simple $1$-D random walk

Comment: But how would you prove this result? I tried using some stopping results and the thing I ended up with is that either $E[T_a]=\infty$ or $E[T_a] \in [0,1]$